# Locally nilpotent groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

$p$-groups are locally nilpotent groups? How can we show it?
I know that a finite $p$-group is nilpotent.
If in general the answer is "no", then what about a FC $p$-group?

Comment: Tarski monsters are non-(locally nilpotent) p-groups.

Comment: There are finitely generated p groups which are not nilpotent.

Comment: Thanks.
Do You know something about $FC\space p$-groups? Are they locally nilpotent groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In periodic $FC$-groups Dietzmann's lemma forces $G$ to be locally nipotent.